# laravel keeps loading or hangs in a loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Sometimes I POST or GET a url and the page just keeps loading forever.

I also get this error when I want to show a non-existing variable in blade or when a form validation fails.

It also keeps loading when I post to something like this:

```
public function postStep2(Request $request)
{
     var_dump($request); die();
}
```

This works:

```
public function postStep2(Request $request)
{
     var_dump(Input::all()); die();
}
```

I'm beginning to think that it has to do with Laravel wanting to show me an error page (via a redirect and ends up in a loop?).

I'm using Laravel 5.2. I tried to downgrade to 5.2.15 and back up to 5.2.22.
Also, httpd.exe is using a lot of CPU when this happens and I end up killing it and restarting wampserver.

What could be the cause of this infinite loading or loop? Why would the first peace of example code load forever, while the second piece of example code is shown almost immediately? Why would the the non-existing variable in blade not show a warning instead of loading forever?

Comment: It's not clear what do you want to achieve.

Comment: It's something that I noticed. I need to post a form, and when I var_dump the request, it keeps loading. When I var_dump the Input it works fine. I dont know how my goal had anything to do with it.

Comment: @Meddie Kindly elaborate your question further.

Comment: I've elaborated my question. I hope this is more clear. Thanks for you help in any case.

Comment: I'm 90% sure it was xdebug. I turned it off, and everything seems to run smooth now. Thanks for you help anyways!

Answer (score 1):

you var dumped a request object, you should do

```
$request->all() or $request->input('input_name')
```

Comment: I know, but this was just to give an example as the one was loading very long and the other wasn't.